# How to make transactions without metamask

Tags: contract-development, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, erc-20, myetherwallet

My account has enough ether to make a transaction. How do i call a payable function that is written in solidity? I tried by calling like this

```
    const Web3 = require('web3');

const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const campaign = require('./build/CampaignFactory');



const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  '12 word mnemonic',
  'https://rinkeby.infura.io/authid',
);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      await campaign.methods.contribute().send({
        from: accounts[0],
        value: web3.utils.toWei(this.state.value, 'ether')
      });
```

But i am getting this error "intrinsic gas too low". Earlier with metamask extension it used to ask for confirmation if i click submit from metamask then the transaction used to get success. Now since i removed metamask extenstion i am getting this error. I want to make this transaction without metamask. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Check for default gas price and gas limit, as metamask might be putting default gas limit and price for you. var gasPrice = web3.eth.gasPrice;
console.log(gasPrice.toString(10));

Comment: Kherwa awesome thanks for the answer. Now i can able to make transactions without metamask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass gasLimit and gasPrice explicitly also.

```
await campaign.methods.contribute().send({
            from: accounts[0],
            value: web3.utils.toWei(this.state.value, 'ether'),
            gas: 'gasLimit',
            gasPrice: 'gasPriceInWei'
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by just passing gas like this.

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  await campaign.methods.contribute().send({
    from: accounts[0],
    value: web3.utils.toWei(this.state.value, 'ether'),
    gas: '1000000'
  });
```